# Image in not showing

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to android programming and I have added long image with size 470x3066px to my app but when I launch app there is only white screen and image in not showing.
Here's my Java code

```
public class Fizikaformulas extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fizikaformulas);

        ActionBar ab = getActionBar(); 
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // Bilde mana layouta
        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.fizformulasimg ); 

        ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        img.setLayoutParams(lp);
        img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        layout.addView(img);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
             // app icon  action bara uzspiesta; uz sakumu
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Sakums.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
            default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); 
    }
    }
```

}

And there's .XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fizformulasimg"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Btw, Do you have any particular reason why you want to add your image dinamically?

Comment: I changed setBackgroundResource() to setImageResource() but nothing  changed and there is only white screen without image.

Comment: let me rephrase - is there need to add your image in your Java code instead of xml?

Comment: See if changing `android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"` works.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setImageResource()` instead of `setBackgroundResource()`.

The problem is that you set the `ImageViews` width and height to `wrap_content`, but the background does not count as content so the `ImageView` will have a size of 0.

By setting the image either as `android:src` in xml or by using `setImageResource()` you can fix that and the `ImageView` will be as big as the image.